Volatility Surface Stress Testing - PCA
I’m currently working on creating historical and hypothetical stress tests, but I’m facing challenges in implementing a method to realistically stress volatility surfaces.
In terms of data, I have daily volatility surfaces from the past two months, as well as 10 years of historical data on the VIX, closing prices, yield curves, etc.
For the historical stress tests, I specifically want to create a COVID scenario, but I don’t have volatility data covering that period (except for the VIX...).
Here’s what I’ve done so far:

I calibrate an SVI model daily on the volatility surfaces (Raw SVI - Arbitrage Free).
I apply PCA on the evolution of the parameters of my SVI models.

The part where I’m currently stuck:

I estimate certain volatility points (ATM short term) by interpolating with the VIX.
I shock the PCA scores to obtain volatility surfaces where the points converge towards the target points through an optimization method.

Unfortunately, I’m encountering two problems:

The regression method between the VIX and IV is not relevant for predicting IV levels in stress situations.
The optimizer converges to surfaces with IV levels significantly lower than those observed during the COVID period. I interpret this as the result of the initial PCA dataset not including any stress periods for single stock volatility.

My question is: What do you think of the method used, and do you have any ideas on how to achieve my goal?

Why don't you just try to get IV data for the COVID period?
